# Calling nant from msbuild

Tags: msbuild, nant

I'm attempting to run an existing nant task from an msbuild targets file.  Is there a way to do this?  Google gives me lots of examples of calling msbuild from nant, but nothing for the other way around.

Thank you.

Comment: Wrap the nant call in An Exec tag are your away?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call NAnt with msbuild's `exec` command. I don't think there's any other command in msbuild to call NAnt specifically.

Calling a NAnt target with msbuild could look something like this

```
<Exec Command="nant -buildfile:your.build yourtarget"/>
```

And if you want NAnt to return something, try this in NAnt:

```
<echo message="yourreturnparameter" file="yourfile.tmp" />
```

And then let msbuild read it:

```
<ReadLinesFromFile File="yourfile.tmp" >
    <Output
      TaskParameter="Lines"
      ItemName="yourreturnparameter"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx